# Button background layer list not drawing properly

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have defined a **layer-list** drawable as background for a button, but it's not displayed correctly, here's the code and the resulting image

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/Button.Login.Radius" />
            <solid android:color="#33455964"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/Button.Login.Radius" />
            <solid android:color="#26a69a" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image: Resulting style]

Why is there a different color on corners?

Comment: you mean to say different color on corners?

Comment: try using different color for shadow and check. also is this a preview or result on device/emulator?

Comment: Using different colors, corners are displayed correctly, maybe because my original color is an rgba with 0.2 alpha value?

Comment: post the values of your colors as well

Comment: I've added hex values

Comment: @Eric Android Studio's preview is completely inaccurate. Always run your app to see how it looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks perfect on emulator (nexus s with api level 19):

[image]

seems like some bug in preview.